# Please can you check my proof of nested closed sets intersection is non-empty

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I tried prove that if $F_1 \supseteq F_2 \supseteq F_3 \supseteq \dots $ is a nested sequence of nonempty closed sets then the intersection $\bigcap_n F_n \neq \varnothing$. I don't know for sure that it is true. Please can you check my proof?

Proof: If $F_i$ are all unbounded then the intersection is also unbounded and therefore not empty. If there is $i$ with $F_i$ bounded then all $F_n$ with $n>i$ are also bounded and therefore compact. Because the intersection of non-empty compact nested sets is nonempty in this case the intersection is also nonempty and therefore the statement is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$F_{n}:=\left[n,\infty\right)\subset\mathbb{R}$ is closed with $F_{1}\supset F_{2}\supset F_{3}\supset\cdots$

However $\cap_{n}F_{n}=\emptyset$.

Under extra condition that the $F_{n}$ are bounded your statement is true. Then you are dealing with compact sets.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true that the intersection of nested unbounded sets is unbounded.

Just look at $F_k=\{2^kn: n\in \mathbb Z\}$. Clearly, each set is closed and unbounded, and clearly, the intersection is $\{0\}$ which is very bounded.

Now take out $0$ from each set and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Your proof contains a number of error. In fact, what you're trying to prove is wrong!

Consider the following example: let $F_{i}=(-\infty,-i]\bigcup[i,+\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$. That is also why your first step is still wrong.

Secondly, bounded and closed do not imply compactness. For example, consider the closed unit sphere in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ space, which is bounded and closed, but not compact. So your 2nd step don't work either.